# Spring + Microservice + JBoss

Tags: spring-mvc, microservices

> We are planning to build an application which has multiple modules
>   (say [Common  which contains Admin, Registration], License Module,
>   Stock Module ). We have planned to use Maven as our build tool

Each module acts like a separate folder(war) where in it has MVC layers in it. Main POM should encapsulate all the modules and form a war file.
If a customer doesn't need License Module, i can just unplug the settings and recreate a war file without much effort.

Now i am struggling to find proper example to build a hierarchy(project structure like above)

Could you please guide me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a parent project then add the child projects as modules. You can easily comment or delete these modules before building the project.

Here is a basic example.

http://www.concretepage.com/build-tools/maven/parent-pom-child-pom-example

You can get a good idea about parent child maven projects from the following thread as well.

[Maven: adding a reference to a parent pom project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395973/maven-adding-a-reference-to-a-parent-pom-project)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. 
Is there any sample links which shows the concrete example which i can have a complete glimpse.

Comment: Here is a good example

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/real_app.htm#MAVEN8929

Alternatively you can search google with "maven multi module project example" and use what you like.

Comment: I cant say it as a maven module.
I am looking for something like this [https://coderanch.com/t/569499/Maven-Building-single-war-file]

Comment: Chandan, all of them are module, you can write pom to create single or multiple war depending upon your requirement. Just try, I am sure you will be able to do it :)